# Ansible change default value according to a condition

Tags: ansible, devops

I need to help with Ansible and make variable base on condition with another user defined variable.
I wrote something like this, but I am pretty sure this is wrong script.

So "{{ vcpu_size }}" has to be define base on user defined "{{ vm_size }}" and I don't know how to do it

Thanks for help

```
    ---
    - name: Deploy VM on XenServer
      hosts: XEN_Server
      become: true

      tasks:

        - name: Load VPS specs for chosen type
          set_fact:
            vcpu_size: "{{ '2' if ({{ vm_size }} == 'S') }}"
            vcpu_size: "{{ '4' if ({{ vm_size }} == 'M') }}"
            vcpu_size: "{{ '6' if ({{ vm_size }} == 'L') }}"
            vcpu_size: "{{ '8' if ({{ vm_size }} == 'XL') }}"

        - debug:
            msg: "Write {{ vcpu_size }} and to be sure {{ vm_size }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the sizes in `group_vars/all`, or somewhere else (such as vars for the role, or in the playbook itself):

```
sizes:
  S: 2
  M: 4
  L: 6
  XL: 8
```

Then use it like this:

```
  set_fact:
    vcpu_size: "{{ sizes[vm_size] }}"
```

Comment: If they're doing the set_fact no matter what, they could even put the vars just on the task itself!

Comment: Thank you so much.. This is better solution for my purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jinja expression like this :

```
  vcpu_size: "{% if vm_size == 'S' %}2{% elif vm_size == 'M' %}4{% else %}some_def_value_here{% endif %}"
```